# How to define LinearLayout Combination

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a layout for four image button. With two buttons in a row, so that it looks like a cube in the layout. Because I want to support API Level 8 i cannot use grid layout, so I tried it with a combination of LinearLayout.

A root LinearLayout with horizontal orientation, this contains two linearlayout with vertical orientation. These contain my buttons, but i does not work as expected, only one row with two buttons is visible. Can someone help me, thanks

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/action_screen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:paddingTop="30px">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

             <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/btn_start_cam"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:onClick="startCamAction"        
                 android:src="@drawable/photo_button" />

             <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/btn_photo_lib"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:onClick="startPhotoLibAction"
                 android:src="@drawable/library_blau" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

             <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/btn_start_barcode"
                 android:onClick="startBarcodeAction"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:src="@drawable/barcode_blau" />

             <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/btn_start_qr_barcode"
                 android:onClick="startQRcodeAction"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:src="@drawable/qr_code_blau" />

            </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the height of the two child LinearLayouts to wrap_content. Otherwise the first LinearLayout will take up the whole height of the parent layout.